# Delete chars from a line in a file using bash

Tags: bash, shell, char, line

I'm trying to delete two chars from a line in a file:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
```

I want the script to delete `#` (hash and a space) from line 2, **but only if the characters are there**.

The problem is the line can look like:

```
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
```

In that case, I don't want the script to change anything.

NOTE: the second word from the right on both lines ("trusty" in this case) may vary on different machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -i 's/^# //' inputFile
```

deletes all occurences of `#` at the beginning of a line in `inputFile`.

Comment: You can also target specific lines by placing an expression before the `s`.  For example you can uncomment the lines containing "trusty" with the expression `'/ trusty /s/^# //'`.

Comment: Thanks SO much. Works.
Added -i to make the changes to the file, and it worked perfectly.

(Here's the whole line: `sed -i '/ deb-src /s/^# //' inputFile`)

Answer (score 1):

This will modify only the second line

```
sed '2,2 s/^# //' input > output
```